# Apply filter based on relationship between objects - Django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models.

```
Account:
    id, name, age, discoverable
Friendship:
    id, requestor, acceptor (requestor and acceptor are Account IDs)
```

I need to write 2 apis.

1. To get all accounts having discoverable=True. Which I accomplished by applying filter on query set like following in AccountViewSet:

   ```
   def filter_queryset(self, queryset):  
       queryset = queryset.filter(discoverable=True).all()     
       return queryset
   ```
2. To get Account detail using following url scheme `<server-url>/accounts/1` where 1 is account id. This api should return:

   - NULL if account 1 is not discoverable and also account 1 is not friend with the authenticated account who is calling this api
   - It should return account 1 detail if both requesting account and account 1 are friends, i.e they have an entry in Friendship table, even if the account 1 is not discoverable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by overriding get_object() method of AccountViewSet as following.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        """
        Fix - If account has already sent a friend request, show it even if user set 
        discoverable = False
        """
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        account = Account.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
        if account:
            if account.is_friends_with(self.request.user, True):
                self.check_object_permissions(self.request, account)
                return account
        #default handling in case they are not friends
        return super(viewsets.GenericViewSet, self).get_object()
```